# Passing an array by reference

Tags: c++, arrays

How does passing a statically allocated array by reference work?

```
void foo(int (&myArray)[100])
{
}

int main()
{
    int a[100];
    foo(a);
}
```

Does `(&myArray)[100]` have any meaning or its just a syntax to pass any array by reference?
I don't understand separate parenthesis followed by big brackets here. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any Rvalue to Lvalue relation with the function parameters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is useful about a reference-to-array parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188991/what-is-useful-about-a-reference-to-array-parameter)

Answer (score 311):

It's a syntax for array references - you need to use `(&array)` to clarify to the compiler that you want a reference to an array, rather than the (invalid) array of references `int & array[100];`.

EDIT: Some clarification.

```
void foo(int * x);
void foo(int x[100]);
void foo(int x[]);
```

These three are different ways of declaring the same function. They're all treated as taking an `int *` parameter, you can pass any size array to them.

```
void foo(int (&x)[100]);
```

This only accepts arrays of 100 integers. You can safely use `sizeof` on `x`

```
void foo(int & x[100]); // error
```

This is parsed as an "array of references" - which isn't legal.

Comment: Why can't we have an array of references e.g. `int a, b, c; int arr[3] = {a, b, c};`?

Comment: Aha, found out [why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164266/why-arrays-of-references-are-illegal#1164306).

Comment: Could someone explain why `void foo(int & x[100]);` is parsed as "array of references" please? Is it because the "from-right-to-left" rule? If yes, it seems to be not consistent with how `void foo(int (&x)[100]);` is parsed as "a reference to a array". Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not right to left, it's inside out, and [] binds tighter than &.

Comment: "This only accepts arrays of 100 integers. You can safely use sizeof on x" is a good clarification to mention.

Answer (score 71):

It's just the required syntax:

```
void Func(int (&myArray)[100])
```

^ Pass array of 100 `int` by reference the parameters name is `myArray`;

```
void Func(int* myArray)
```

^ Pass an array. Array decays to a pointer. Thus you lose size information.

```
void Func(int (*myFunc)(double))
```

^ Pass a function pointer. The function returns an `int` and takes a `double`. The parameter name is `myFunc`.

Comment: How do we pass a variable size array as a reference ?

Comment: @ShivamArora You templateize the function and make the size a template parameter.

Answer (score 31):

It is a syntax. In the function arguments `int (&myArray)[100]` parenthesis that enclose the `&myArray` are necessary. if you don't use them, you will be passing an `array of references` and that is because the `subscript operator []` has higher precedence over the `& operator`.

E.g. `int &myArray[100] // array of references`

So, by using `type construction ()` you tell the compiler that you want a reference to an array of 100 integers.

E.g `int (&myArray)[100] // reference of an array of 100 ints`

Comment: "if you don't use them, you will be passing an `array of references`" - which of course, cannot exist, so you'd get a compile error. It's amusing to me that the operator precedence rules insist this must happen by default anyway.

Comment: Is there's any more tutorial about type construction () ?

Comment: Thanks, I needed an explanation that included the reason about operator precedence, which gives a sense to why it should be done this way.

Comment: @BugShotGG, thanks so much for providing me with a head-slap "oh, that's what's causing this" moment by mentioning operator precedence.  I guess this is inevitable because [] needs left to right associativity while & needs right to left so they can't be in the same level.  And I guess ++/-- need to be above & so pointer incrementation works as expected.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 20):

The following creates a generic function, taking an array of any size and of any type by reference:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t S>
void my_func(T (&arr)[S]) {
   // do stuff
}
```

[play with the code.](https://godbolt.org/z/nPqUXY)

Comment: [Good writeup on how to use this pattern to make a safe strcpy](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/).

Answer (score 6):

Arrays are default passed by pointers. You can try modifying an array inside a function call for better understanding.

Comment: Arrays can not be passed by value. If the function receives a pointer, an array decays to a pointer to its first element. I'm not sure what you are trying to say here.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'm trying to say that "Arrays can not be passed by value" as you said before, they are default passed by reference

Comment: Array are neither passed by value nor reference. They are passed by pointers. If arrays are passed by reference by default, you will have no problem using sizeof on them. But that is not the case. Arrays decays to pointers when passed into a function.

Comment: Arrays can be passed by reference OR by degrading to a pointer. For example, using `char arr[1];  foo(char arr[]).`, arr degrades to a pointer; while using `char arr[1];  foo(char (&arr)[1])`, arr is passed as a reference. It's notable that the former form is often regarded as ill-formed since the dimension is lost.

Comment: Re, "Arrays are...passed by pointers." That description sounds unconventional at best, and it may be confusing to newbies. The _name_ of an array variable, is a valid expression whose value is a pointer the the first member of the array. If you have some function `foo(T* t)`, and you have an array `T a[N];` then when you write `foo(a);` I think it would be more correct to say that you are passing a pointer, not passing an array, and you are passing the pointer by value.

Comment: It's important to distinguish between a parameter declared as an array reference and a parameter declared as simply an array type. The latter will effectively be treated as a pointer via 'decay to pointer' semantics and the size of the array will be ignored. The former though will be able to enforce the correct array size through the type system and in a template context the size of the passed array can be deduced.

Comment: @user3437460 Commenting on old comment since it has a lot of votes: **in C++ arrays can be passed by reference**.