# Is there a way to pass a string literal as reference in C++

Tags: c++, char, pass-by-reference

Within C++ it is common to pass by reference instead of pointer if a value can not be NULL.

Suppose I have a function with the following signature, which is often used with a string literal.

```
void setText( const char* text );
```

I was wondering how I could change the function in such a way that it accepts a reference (and has the advantage not to accept NULL)?

- If I would change it to `(const char& text)` then it would be a ref to a single char. From which the address can ba taken inside the function... but feels not nice.
- Another option would be `(const std::string& text)` which has the disadvantage that it always calls a constructor and does some dynamic memory allocation.

Any other common ways, or just stick to the `std::string&` or the `char*` ?

Comment: Take a `const std::string &`. It will be automatically constructed from a C string. "it always calls a constructor and does some dynamic memory allocation" – most likely no, if you're using a reasonable standard library and compiler.

Comment: Look around for a `string_ref`. I don't think its standard but it makes a light reference wrapper for `std::string` or `const char*`.

Comment: `const std::string&`, this is where RAII really helps you out.

Comment: string literals are char arrays so you could take an array by reference templated on the array size. I don't think I'd prefer such a template solution over `std::string` though.

Comment: If you are using C++11, you can create a `setText(const char * text)` -- with the reference advantages and a `setText(std::nullptr_t)` to handle NULLs.

Comment: @user666412: overrides are determined at compile time so a nullptr_t would only catch calls using a literal null.

Comment: Um this is _not_ why we choose references over pointers. If your function takes a pointer that must not be null, simply document that as a precondition.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I would just keep the `const char* text` function and add an overload `const std::string& text` function that calls the first one with `setText(text.c_str())`

Answer (score -1):

There's a slight problem here in that C++ and references-to-arrays aren't the best pair. For reference, see: [C++ pass an array by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007986/c-pass-an-array-by-reference)

Since you're talking about binding a reference to a string, and a string is an array of characters, we run into that problem head-on. In light of this, the best we can really do is bind a ref to a const char*, which looks like this:

```
void ref(const char* const& s);
```

But this doesn't do what you want; this binds a reference to a pointer, and all it guarantees is that the pointer itself exists, not that it's pointing to a valid string literal.
This same problem is present in the std::string& examples: those only guarantee that you've bound to a std::string object, but that string could very well be empty, so you still haven't guaranteed yourself a string that has anything of value in it.

In the end, I'll second what Zan says. const char* is a well respected idiom passing string literals, and then having a second overload that binds to strings is a nice convenience.

(One last note: std::string doesn't "always" allocate memory. Implementations with the small string optimization will skip it for strings as long as 23 characters.)