# Preferred way to pass a string literal into a library function that requires char** in C++

Tags: c++, string, char

I am trying to call function `void func(char** argv)` with a string literal "test.exe" in C++.
My current solution is

```
char* name = "test.exe";
func(&name);
```

However, the compiler complains since string literals are of type `const char*`. What is the current recommended way to resolve this?

I've read several answers, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27365824/is-there-a-way-to-pass-a-string-literal-as-reference-in-c), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/how-to-convert-a-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760500/why-is-passing-a-string-literal-into-a-char-argument-only-sometimes-a-compiler), etc, but all the answers I've found are either:

1. Use std::string::c_str() which I don't want to do since I don't want to allocate the memory for a new std::string, or
2. Change func to take a `const char *`, which I cannot do as it is contained in an external library.

Comment: If the function is declared without `const`, that implies that it may modify the string you pass in. So you can't call it with a literal, since they can't be modified.

Comment: And the name `argv` suggests that it should be an array of strings, not a single string. If the function doesn't also take `argc`, it will expect the array to end with a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: Side note: `std::string::c_str()` can't help here. It also returns a `const` pointer. `std::string::data`, on the other hand... Will compile but is almost certainly a bad idea.

Comment: It's possible that they're just sloppy C programmers. For historical reasons, C string literals are `char*` rather than `const char*`.

Comment: I was just simplifying the problem. The full signature I'm trying to call is `int mono_jit_exec (MonoDomain *domain, MonoAssembly *assembly, int argc, char *argv[])`

Comment: It entirely depends on the external lib. The function may never modify and the missing `const` is just a relic of ancient C, allowing you to simply use `const_cast`, it may require the contents pointed to to be modifiable or even to have a minimum size...

Comment: In that case they most certainly want an array of strings.

Comment: You're meant to just pass in the argc and argv from the terminal, but I wanted to simplify having to provide that every time I test it by just hard coding the values for now

Comment: Just use `const_cast()` to override the default type of the string literal.

Comment: I agree they want an array of strings @fabian, I'm not positive how I should write that in C though

Comment: Ok so what I have now based on your suggestions is
`char* h = const_cast<char*>("test.exe");`
`mono_jit_exec (domain, assembly, 1, &h);`
Is this a good solution?

Comment: Should work.  You'll soon know...

Comment: Seems to be working, just hoping this won't cause one of those scary C memory bugs

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: With the (lack of) information given in the question, it is really opinion-based.   For example, if `func()` ASSUMES the pointer it is passed is the address of a first element of an array of `char *`, where the end of the array is marked by a null pointer, then the usage `func(&name)` in the question WOULD give undefined behaviour, regardless of any concerns of `const` or otherwise.   The general answer is to examine documentation (or code if you have it) for `func()` and pass something that will give well-defined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

It depends whether the function actually modifies the string.

If it doesn't, then you can just cast away the `const`:

```
char* name = const_cast<char*>("test.exe");
func(&name);
```

String literals are not allowed to be modified though.  That means that if the function *does* modify the string you pass it, then you'll need to copy the string literal to a local, modifiable variable:

```
char name_arr[] = "test.exe";
char* name = name_arr;
func(&name);
```