# C++ reference byte array

Tags: c++, ref

I have an issue with C++ and creating a reference byte[].

In C# my method is:

```
public static void SetBitAt(ref byte[] Buffer, int Pos, int Bit, bool Value)
    {
        byte[] Mask = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80 };
        if (Bit < 0) Bit = 0;
        if (Bit > 7) Bit = 7;

        if (Value)
            Buffer[Pos] = (byte)(Buffer[Pos] | Mask[Bit]);
        else
            Buffer[Pos] = (byte)(Buffer[Pos] & ~Mask[Bit]);
    }
```

I want to translate it to C++, but I can't get the `ref`working for C++. I saw something about the `&` symbol and I tried something like this:

```
void SetBitAt(byte& buffer[], int Pos, int Bit, bool Value)
{
    byte Mask[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80 };
    if (Bit < 0) Bit = 0;
    if (Bit > 7) Bit = 7;

    if (Value)
    {
        buffer[Pos] = (byte)(buffer[Pos] | Mask[Bit]);
    }
    else
    {
        buffer[Pos] = (byte)(buffer[Pos] & ~Mask[Bit]);
    }
}
```

but then I get the Error:

> 'buffer': arrays of references are illegal.

So how can I change my C++ code to work with a reference array?

EDIT:
I use this method for setting a buffer, but it doesn't change when I use this method.

other class:

```
buffer = ReadDB(2);          //Read the values in the DataBlock
SetBitAt(buffer, 0,0 true);  //Set bit 0,0 to 1(true)
WriteDB(2, buffer);          //Write the values to the Datablock
```

but the buffer doesn't change. its the same value.

Comment: "ref" is enabled only in C++ CLR. That's why it isn't working here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pass array by reference, you should

```
void SetBitAt(byte (buffer&)[10], int Pos, int Bit, bool Value)
```

But in your case, you don't need that, just

```
void SetBitAt(byte buffer[], int Pos, int Bit, bool Value)
```

Note in this case array will decay to pointer (i.e. `byte*`), that means the size of array won't be reserved as pass by reference would.

Comment: check my question, ive added some extra information where I use this method for.

Comment: Bart, this answer is correct.   In C and C++, an array is passed as a pointer, so elements can be referenced.  Since all your code is doing is referencing elements, no more is needed.

Comment: @Bart: You've now gone from the original question into debug-help-me mode, but you're missing the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We've answered the question correctly and you might simply need to do further debugging of your logic.

Comment: @ray yep you are right, I'll just create a new question for my next problem

Comment: @Bart Could you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for it? I've tried one [here](http://rextester.com/TDQWI55137), please check it. You might need to check whether `SetBitAt()` set the value correctly.

Comment: @songyuanyao I tested it myself and it seems the buffer does change. Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

> 'buffer': arrays of references are illegal.

This is due to operator precedence. Saying `byte &buffer[]` is an array of references, while saying `byte (&buffer)[size]` is a reference to an array.

See [C++ pass an array by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007986/c-pass-an-array-by-reference) for more details.

> So how can I change my C++ code to work with a reference array?

When passing your array as a function argument, you should drop `&` symbol. You can still modify the contents of your array because the array's address is passed instead.

Assuming you have a `typedef` of `char` to `byte`, your function signature should look like this:

```
void SetBitAt(byte buffer[], int Pos, int Bit, bool Value) { ... }
```

Note that the above is equivalent to passing a pointer:

```
void SetBitAt(byte *buffer, int Pos, int Bit, bool Value) { ... }
```

Modifying the contents of your array is still a matter of saying `buffer[Pos] = // some value;`

This post on [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) should be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it simply be like this:

```
void SetBitAt(byte buffer[], int Pos, int Bit, bool Value)
{
    byte Mask[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80 };
    if (Bit < 0) Bit = 0;
    if (Bit > 7) Bit = 7;

    if (Value)
    {
        buffer[Pos] = (byte)(buffer[Pos] | Mask[Bit]);
    }
    else
    {
        buffer[Pos] = (byte)(buffer[Pos] & ~Mask[Bit]);
    }
}
```

In this way, buffer is passed as a pointer, and buffer[Pos] references to the Pos-th element of buffer. It is plain C, but it should work.

Comment: I did that, but then it doesn't change my buffer, see my edited question for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it simply by address as:

```
void SetBitAt(byte* buffer, int Pos, int Bit, bool Value) { ... }
```

or simply as:

```
void SetBitAt(byte buffer[], int Pos, int Bit, bool Value) { ... }
```

Either one will tell the compiler that byte pointer is passed to function, althrough with second header you omit pointer arithmetics ;)

Comment: `buffer` and `&buffer` are not the same.   They have different types.

Comment: My bad, @Peter name of an array is constant pointer to that array. Thank you!