# Does span propagate const?

Tags: c++, constants, c++20, std-span

The standard containers propagate const.  That is, their elements are automatically const if the containers themselves are const.  For example:

```
const std::vector vec{3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6};
ranges::fill(vec, 314); // impossible

const std::list lst{2, 7, 1, 8, 2, 8, 1, 8};
ranges::fill(lst, 272); // impossible
```

Builtin arrays also propagate const:

```
const int arr[] {1, 4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5};
ranges::fill(arr, 141); // impossible
```

However, I noticed that `std::span` (presumably) does not propagate const.  Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <span>

namespace ranges = std::ranges;

int main()
{
    int arr[] {1, 7, 3, 2, 0, 5, 0, 8};

    const std::span spn{arr};
    ranges::fill(spn, 173);               // this compiles

    assert(ranges::count(arr, 173) == 8); // passes
}
```

Why does this code work fine?  Why does `std::span` treat const differently than the standard containers?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Propagating const for a type like `span` doesn't actually make much sense, since it cannot protect you from anything anyway.

Consider:

```
void foo(std::span<int> const& s) {
    // let's say we want this to be ill-formed
    // that is, s[0] gives a int const& which
    // wouldn't be assignable
    s[0] = 42;

    // now, consider what this does
    std::span<int> t = s;

    // and this
    t[0] = 42;
}
```

Even if `s[0]` gave an `int const&`, `t[0]` surely gives an `int&`. And `t` refers to the exactly same elements as `s`. It's a copy after all, and `span` doesn't own its elements - it's a reference type. Even if `s[0] = 42` failed, `std::span(s)[0] = 42` would succeed. This restriction wouldn't do anyone any good.

The difference with the regular containers (e.g. `vector`) is that the copies here still refer to the same elements, whereas copying a `vector` would give you entirely new elements.

The way to have `span` refer to immutable elements isn't to make the `span` itself `const`, it's to make the underlying elements themselves `const`. That is: `span<T const>`, not `span<T> const`.

Comment: Good point, explains why span cannot propagate const sensibly.  Also, is it intended that `s` is a reference?

Comment: @L.F. No the ref isn't important, it's just that const& parameters are a pretty typical way to end up with a const span.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it explains better than mine.

Comment: Why allow `std::span<int> t = s;` to work if `s` is a const span in the first place? The compiler doesn't allow that when using pointers (as the other answer tells us to compare span to a pointer).

Comment: @GabrielGalli Huh? You can definitely copy a pointer.

Comment: I mean like this: https://godbolt.org/z/GKEcbefzn

Comment: @GabrielGalli Well, sure, but that's not what we're talking about. `s` in my example isn't a `span<int const>`, it's a `span<int> const&` (it's the `span` itself which is const, but its contents are still mutable). That's the equivalent of trying to construct an `int*` from an `int* const&` (it's a const pointer to a mutable int), which of course works: https://godbolt.org/z/6hs1xqxc5

Comment: Ohhh I'm sorry I got confused, that's right! Thanks

Comment: No, this can not be the explanation and the reason why. The initialization t = s should never work if s is const and t is not.

What should really happen, for span to propagate const, is to make any "span<int> const" behave implicitly like a "span<int const> const". Which is what containers do.

Comment: @Toughy `span` isn't a container. Also what you're arguing would mean that `span<int>` isn't copyable, which would make it unusable.

Comment: It would still work. Temporaries can be passed using the move constructor, and explicit copies written by the developer should not work, the same way you do not copy a span<int const> into a span<int>

Answer (score 8):

Think of pointers.  Pointers do not propagate const either.  The constness of the pointer is independent from the constness of the element type.

Considered the modified Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <span>

namespace ranges = std::ranges;

int main()
{
    int var = 42;

    int* const ptr{&var};
    ranges::fill_n(ptr, 1, 84); // this also compiles

    assert(var == 84);          // passes
}
```

It is by design that `std::span` is kind of a pointer to a contiguous sequence of elements.  Per [[span.iterators]](http://eel.is/c++draft/span.iterators):

> ```
> constexpr iterator begin() const noexcept;
> constexpr iterator end() const noexcept;
> ```

Note that `begin()` and `end()` return a non-const iterator regardless of whether the span itself is const or not.  Thus, `std::span` does not propagate const, in a way that is analogous to pointers.  The constness of the span is independent from the constness of the element type.

```
const1 std::span<const2 ElementType, Extent>
```

The first `const` specifies the constness of the span itself.  The second `const` specifies the constness of the elements.  In other words:

```
      std::span<      T> // non-const span of non-const elements
      std::span<const T> // non-const span of     const elements
const std::span<      T> //     const span of non-const elements
const std::span<const T> //     const span of     const elements
```

If we change the declaration of `spn` in the Example to:

```
std::span<const int, 8> spn{arr};
```

The code fails to compile, just like the standard containers.  It doesn't matter whether you mark `spn` itself as const in this regard.  (You can't do things like `spn = another_arr`, though, if you mark it as const)

(Note: you can still use class template argument deduction with the help of `std::as_const`:

```
std::span spn{std::as_const(arr)};
```

Just don't forget to `#include <utility>`.)

Comment: Note that I don't have access to a compiler that can actually compile the code (yet), so I stand to be corrected.