# error on Visual c++

Tags: c++

```
void input(int B[XAM][XAM])
{                int i,j,a;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
        for (j=0; j<3; j++) {
            scanf("%d",&B[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
        for (j=0; j<3; j++) {
            printf("%d ",B[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}


void main()
{
#define XAM 3
    int pilih,A[10],B[3][3],i,j;

    input(&B[XAM][XAM]);

    for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
        for (j=0; j<3; j++) {
            printf("%d ",B[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    getch(); 
}
```

why when i try to run the program, I already used "Pass by reference", but still when I call the output from void main, the output didn't the same as my input from the procedure,
but if I call the output from the procedure, there is no problem
can someone help me why pass the reference didn't work?
thanks

Comment: `B[3][3]` (which is the expansion of `B[XAM][XAM]`) in the function call accesses an element which is out of bounds. Also, `&` in the caller code isn't going to pass the argument by reference. The `&` has to be in the signature and the caller code looks like pass by value. Also, multi-dimension arrays have their pitfalls, and I'm not sure if this code is going to work as expected. I very much recommend `std::vector` (for multi dimensions, nest them or index it like `x + y*XAM`)

Comment: Why not use `std::vector` or some other suitable container instead of raw arrays if you're really writing C++ code (i.e. not C)?

Comment: main should return an int:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c

Comment: How can this compile? The compiler does not know what `XAM` is at the declaration point of input. It should abort execution at that point...

Answer (score 2):

you are passing the address (&) of [3][3] element of B using:

```
&B[3][3]
```

Just write

```
input(B);
```

Note that passing by reference is not done when you are calling funtcion, but when you are defining, so:

```
int foo(Foo& f);
```

passes `f` as reference when using it simply like `foo(f);`

But
    int foo(Foo f);

in case where `Foo` is not a pointer (your `B` is a pointer) would end in compilation error, when trying `foo(&f)`.

Also it would be good if you used `XAM` constant in `B` definition

```
B[3][3] -> B[XAM][XAM]
```

And turn on warnings in your compilator!

Answer (score 1):

You want to pass the array by reference.

Whether or not a function parameter is passed by reference or by value is decided at the **function's signature**. You have to change the parameter type such that it's a reference to an array. That's done by adding the ampersand `&` to the parameter name.

For arrays, parentheses need to be added which needs getting used to:

```
void input(int (&B)[XAM][XAM]) {
    // ...
}
```

When calling that function, simply pass `B` without mentioning the dimensions or using the `&` operator (that does something different when used at values!). That means, calling the function is written *as if* the argument was passed *by value* (no syntactical difference there), but of course it is passed by reference since the function's signature says so.

```
input(B);
```

Indeed, passing arrays by reference is the only way to pass an array as an array. Otherwise (if your parameter looks like `int B[XAM][XAM]`), only a pointer to the first element is actually passed, and it isn't treated as an array within the function. You can easily check how it is treated in the function body by using the `sizeof` operator.

Related question: [Passing an array by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724171/passing-an-array-by-reference)