# Call by reference with 2D Arrays

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get this simple c++ program to work but I keep bouncing from error to error.
Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int row = 3;
const int col = 3;
int array[row][col];

void print(int array[row][col]){
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            cout << array[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void setValues(int (&array), int value){
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            array[i][j] = value; //invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    setValues(array, 30); //Expected primary-expression before ',' token + Invalid Arguments 'Candidates are: void setValue(int &, int)
    print(array); //expected primary=expression before ')' token
    return 0;
}
```

I want to change values in a 2D array with a function.

Comment: try this typedef int array[row][col] Array; and use it like  setValues(Array, 30);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
typedef int array[row][col];
```

What you are doing here is creating an alias for `int` that's called `array[row][col]`. Just remove the `typedef` and it will work just fine.

**Edit**: Forgot about the other error

```
void setValues(int (&array)[row][col], int value)
```

It also works like this

```
void setValues(int array[row][col], int value)
```

Comment: Removed the typedef but the errors are still there.

Comment: @user74096 by removing the `&` you completely go around what the question is about. The new version of setValues() suggested by Catalin uses pass by value and not pass by reference. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5724184/1559401 for more information. Also if the array variable is declared as it is right now (that is - its scope is global) you don't need to bother passing it to a function as a parameter at all since it is perfectly visible inside the function's body due to its scope.

Comment: @rbaleksandar I don't understand what you're referring too. The corrected version of the code is      `void setValues(int (&array)[row][col], int value)` is that not call by reference?

Comment: @user74096 I was actually referring to `void setValues(int array[row][col], int value)` which is given as alternative by Catalin and is call by value and not by reference unlike the one you have pointed in your comment.

Comment: @rbaleksandar There's no such thing as call by value with arrays.

Comment: My bad. I'm so used to using `*` and `&` that `int array[][]` has started to look alien to me. LOL