# C++ array size inferring from integer template

Tags: c++, templates

I came across the template version `_snwprintf_s`

from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f30dzcf6.aspx):

```
template <size_t size>
int _snwprintf_s(
   wchar_t (&buffer)[size],
   size_t count,
   const wchar_t *format [,
   argument] ... 
); // C++ only
```

I understand how to use it, and I'm familiar with c++ templates and the possibility to use templates with an integer.

What is the type of `wchar_t (&buffer)[size]`? Is it a reference to a wchar_t, if so then what the [size] mean? what is this called?

I'm guessing the compiler infers the size somehow but this is the first time I've come across such syntax and would appreciate an explanation as I haven't found anything on it by myself (probably since I don't know what to search for).

Also, If you can explain how this works behind the scene, that'd be great.

EDIT:

I'm more interested at how this works compiler-wise, less about the type that is passed, which is as mentioned explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724171/passing-an-array-by-reference)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wchar_t (&buffer)[size]` is a reference to array, just as you would write in plain C `wchar_t (*buffer)[size]` which is a pointer to the array.

ypu can think of a reference as "constant - auto-dereferencing - pointers" and in 99% of the times they are implemented as such.

the point is that C++ compiler can, on compile time only, deduce the type of the arguments and call the right template function.

thus, 
`L"hi"` would be deduce as `wchar_t[3]` and call `_snwprintf_s<3>`.

this is of course not applicable for something like `wchar_t t* = malloc(3*sizeof(wchar_t));`, since it's allcoated on run time, and the type of `t` is `wchar_t*`

Answer (score 2):

`buffer` is a reference to an object of type `wchar_t[size]`: that is, a reference to an array of size `size` of `wchar_t`.

This is very similar to making the parameter `wchar_t buffer[]`, but there are some advantages: e.g. it lets you do the the template argument deduction here, and I've also seen optimizers perform better in some situations when arrays are passed in this manner.

Comment: It also isn't a pointer to `wchar_t`, unlike `wchar_t buffer[]`. So it can't bind to such a pointer.

Comment: The answer was reading fine, and I was about to upvote it, until I read this *"This is **very similar** to making the parameter wchar_t buffer[]"*.