# Implicitly passing the length of arrays in parameters in c++

Tags: c++, parameter-passing

I once saw code (from a source apparently reliable enough to cause me to remember it) that seemed to convey the length of the array while passing them in a funtion (See example below):

```
void foo(int [m][n] array)
{
//m and n are the rows and columns of the array
//code
}
```

However, I'm unable to find that source and am beginning to wonder if I got it all wrong and maybe, even imagined it? Can someone care to comment?

Comment: Try looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724171/passing-an-array-by-reference#5724184).

Comment: `template <std::size_t M, std::size_t N>
void foo(int (&array)[M][N];`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use templates to *deduce* the static size from the argument if you accept the array *by reference*:

```
template<std::size_t X, std::size_t Y>
void print(int(&array)[X][Y])
{
    for(std::size_t x = 0; x < X; ++x)
    {
        for(std::size_t y = 0; y < Y; ++y)
            std::cout << ' ' << array[x][y];
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    int array[][3] = {{1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6}};

    print(array);
}
```

**Output:**

```
 1 3 5
 2 4 6
```

Comment: @hexcode No, the size of dynamically created arrays is not deducable, you simply have to get it right manually.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you can do

```
void foo(int array[m][n])
```

as long as both `m` and `n` are integral constant expressions. `m` will be ignored, while `n` will affect the parameter type. The above is equivalent to

```
void foo(int array[][n])
void foo(int (*array)[n])
```

Whether this is similar to what you saw - only you can know.

Answer (score 0):

does the preceding line look something like the following?

```
template <size_t m, size_t n>
```

The compiler will create a uniquely named version of the function for each array size used.