# C++ template parameter T(*)[]

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

Here's the source code of [std::default_delete](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/default_delete) from Visual Studio 2017 Community edition.

```
template<class _Ty>
struct default_delete<_Ty[]>
{
    // default deleter for unique_ptr to array of unknown size
    constexpr default_delete() _NOEXCEPT = default;

    template<class _Uty, class = typename enable_if<is_convertible<_Uty(*)[], _Ty(*)[]>::value, void>::type>
    default_delete(const default_delete<_Uty[]>&) _NOEXCEPT
    {
        // construct from another default_delete
    }

    template<class _Uty, class = typename enable_if<is_convertible<_Uty(*)[], _Ty(*)[]>::value, void>::type>
    void operator()(_Uty *_Ptr) const _NOEXCEPT
    {
        // delete a pointer
        static_assert(0 < sizeof (_Uty), "can't delete an incomplete type");
        delete[] _Ptr;
    }
};
```

I noticed the template parameters `_Uty(*)[]` and `_Ty(*)[]` in `is_convertible<_Uty(*)[], _Ty(*)[]>` inside array specialization.

If it was `_Ty(&)[]` then I would know for sure that it's a reference to array of type _Ty, as covered in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724171/passing-an-array-by-reference#), but have no clue whatsoever on what `_Ty(*)[]` means.
It'll be really helpful if someone can shed light on this exotic template param.

**EDIT:**
Many thanks to all of ya! I managed to rig up a function taking pointer to array.

```
template <typename T>
T* func0(T(*parr)[], std::initializer_list<T> args)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (T arg : args)
        (*parr)[i++] = arg;
    return *parr;
}

template <typename T, unsigned S>
T* func1(T(*parr)[S], std::initializer_list<T> args)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (T arg : args)
        (*parr)[i++] = arg;
    return *parr;
}

int main(void)
{
    std::string strs[5];
    //std::string* pstrs = func1(&strs, {"133", "233", "333", "433", "533"}); // Not working! Cannot deduce template param T from args
    std::string* pstrs = func1<std::string, 5>(&strs, {"133", "233", "333", "433", "533"}); // Works fine!
    //std::string* pstrs = func0<std::string, 5>(&strs, {"133", "233", "333", "433", "533"}); // Not working! No instance of function template match
    return 0;
}
```

I wonder why template param T cannot be deduced from args passed to func1 ?
Also, it seems that the size information `S` in `T(*parr)[S]` is a must.

Comment: Pointer to an array of type `_Ty`, of course. E.g. this is what you'd get if you apply address-of `&` operator to a reference to an array of type `_Ty` (whose existence you already know about).

Comment: `T(*)[]` is just a pointer to an array of an unspecified number of `T` objects. The confusing bit is testing its convertability as pointers (or references) to arrays of one type do not convert to pointers (or references) of other arrays. I *guess* non-`const` to `const` conversion is still allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

_Ty(&)[] is a reference to a C-style array.

_Ty(*)[] is a pointer to a C-style array.

Comment: *incomplete* C-style array.

Comment: After googling with keyword `pointer to C-style array` I found a nice [post](http://cplusplus.bordoon.com/specializeForCharacterArrays.html#overloads) on its usage. The author only show its usage in his code sample without any explanation or referring to it.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks u r my savior! I managed to find tons of information using the keyword `incomplete C-style array`.