# Passing by reference issue?

Tags: c++, arrays, reference

The problem i am trying to pass array `char arr[6] = {"1","2",etc.}` to a function that takes parameter like this `void foo(char* &arr,...)` and it does not work. Can anyone explain it to me please ?

Comment: Because an array is not a pointer. And a pointer is not an array

Comment: Those questions are answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing an array by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724171/passing-an-array-by-reference)

Comment: Does `char arr[6] = {"1","2",etc.}` actually compile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`char arr[6]` is an array.

`char* &arr` is a(n lvalue) reference to a pointer.

Now, since the argument is not of correct type, it has to be converted. An array implicitly decays (decaying is a kind of conversion) into a pointer to first element.

But this decayed pointer is a temporary (an rvalue). Non-const lvalue references can not refer to rvalues, so it would be ill-formed to call `foo` with an array argument.

---

You can create a pointer variable; that can be passed to `foo`:

```
char* ptr = arr;
foo(ptr, ...);
```

The function may then modify that pointer (i.e. make it point to some other `char` object), since the reference is non-const.

---

PS. There is something very wrong with the initialization of your array. `"1"` and `"2"` are not `char` objects.