# How to pass an array of vectors by reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

int main(void)
{
    vector<int> gr[10];

    function(gr);
}
```

How should I define that function calling by reference rather than by value?

Comment: The same as you would with any other type.

Comment: Similar to the way you would define a function taking a reference to an array of any other type.

Comment: I've tried to define it as

void function(vector<int> &gr);

but its giving me an error.

Comment: *I've tried to define it as void function(vector<int> &gr)* -- First, do you know that you've declared an array of `vector<int>`?  I ask this because I see a lot of new programmers make the mistake of declaring an array of vectors instead of just  `std::vector<int> gr;`.  A `vector` itself is an "array" -- a dynamic array.

Comment: Wrong spelling in title: you probably want to pass by reference an array of vectors. It could be simpler to use `std::array`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've needed to implement Adjacency Lists in Graphs. I guess I need an array of vectors then?

Comment: Then use simply `std::array<std::vector<int>, 10> gr;`, as others have mentioned in the answers.

Comment: @CaesarK I always implemented adjacency lists with std::vector<std::vector<something>>

Comment: A vector is basically an object oriented array. Whenever you need and array, you can just use a vector (or maybe std::array<>).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For pass by reference:

```
void foo( vector<int> const (&v)[10] )
```

Or sans `const` if `foo` is going to modify the actual argument.

---

To avoid the problems of the inside-out original C syntax for declarations you can do this:

```
template< size_t n, class Item >
using raw_array_of_ = Item[n];

void bar( raw_array_of_<10, vector<int>> const& v );
```

---

However, if you had used `std::array` in your `main` function, you could do just this:

```
void better( std::array<vector<int>, 10> const& v );
```

But this function doesn't accept a raw array as argument, only a `std::array`.

Comment: `gr` is an array

Comment: Done..,,,,,,...'

Answer (score 5):

```
auto function(vector<int> (&gr)[10]) { ... }
```

It should be the right syntax to pass an array of `std::vector<int>` [by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724171/passing-an-array-by-reference).

Comment: Isn't it possible to not specify "10" in the function?

Comment: @CaesarK: Not when the array is passed by reference.

Comment: @CaesarK AFAIK, it isn't possible if you pass by reference.

Comment: What if the size (10 here) is taken from user dynamically, so we have a vector like `vector<int> gr[n];`

Answer (score 4):

To pass an array of ten `int`s by reference you would use:

```
void foo(int (&gr)[10]);
```

Similarly, for an array of ten `std::vector`s it would be:

```
void foo(std::vector<int> (&gr)[10]);
```

That being said an array of vectors is somewhat unusual structure. Prefer `std::array` to raw arrays.