# C++: Nested For-loops over 2 dimensional array with "auto"

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, auto

To loop over a 3x3 array called "a" in C++ i used the following code.

```
int a[3][3] {};
for(auto &b: a) {
  for(auto &c: b) {
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
  }
}
```

If I had to replace the "auto", I would intuitively try

```
int a[3][3] {};
for(int &(b[3]): a) {
  for(int &c: b) {
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
  }
}
```

But this does not work. Instead I figured out that the following works.

```
int a[3][3] {};
for(int (&b)[3]: a) {
  for(int &c: b) {
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
  }
}
```

**So the question is: Why does the latter example work?**

I thought I needed a reference to an array of length 3, but instead I need an array of length 3 containing references.

Comment: `int (&b)[3]` This is a reference to a `int[3]`. It's a tricky syntax. So you do have a reference to an array of length 3.

Comment: Your "reading" is unfortunately wrong, `int &(b)[3]` is parsed as an array of references, while `int (&b)[3]` is a reference to an array of size 3. (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724171/passing-an-array-by-reference/5724184#5724184)

Comment: Because `for(int i=0; i<3; i++) for(int j=0; j<3; j++) { std::cout << a[i][j] << std:endl;` would have been too readable and simple. So lets try to convolute that fast, readable code into oblivion, C++1x providing all the tools. Bonus points if the machine code also turns slower.

Comment: I think `int (&b)[3]: a` is still way too readable. Do you have any ideas to make it even more unreadable?

Comment: using I3 = int[3]; for(I3 &b: a) { // looks even worse here when I looks like 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array like this

```
T a[N1][N2][N3];
```

where `T` is some type specifier and `N1`, `N2`, and `N3` the sizes of the array then a reference to this array will look like

```
T ( &ra )[N1][N2][N3]  = a;
```

If you need to declare a reference to the element of the array that (the element) has the type `T[N2][N3]` then you can write for example

```
T ( &e )[N2][N3] = a[0];
```

Returning to your example you declared an array

```
int a[3][3] {};
```

elements of this array have the type `int[3]`. So to declare a reference to elements of the array you have to write

```
for ( int ( %row )[3] : a )
```

As for this declaration

```
int &(b[3])
```

(where the parentheses are redundant) then it declares an array of three elements with the type `int &`. However according to the C++ Standard you may not declare an array of references.

From the C++ Standard (8.3.4 Arrays)

> 1 In a declaration T D where D has the form

```
D1 [ constant-expressionopt] attribute-specifier-seqopt
```

> and the type of the identifier in the declaration T D1 is
>   “derived-declarator-type-list T”, then the type of the identifier of D
>   is an array type; if the type of the identifier of D contains the auto
>   type-specifier, the program is ill-formed. **T is called the array
>   element type; this type shall not be a reference type, the (possibly
>   cvqualified) type void, a function type or an abstract class
>   type**....

Answer (score 1):

`int &(b[3])` is equivalent to `int & b[3]`, i.e., an *array of references to `int`* whose length is three. This does not correspond to the type of the elements in the array `int a[3][3]`.

The elements in the array `int a[3][3]` are of type `int[3]`, i.e., an *array of `int` whose length is three*. By declaring instead `b` as `int(&b)[3]` you declare a reference to such a type.