# (C++) How to dynamic array parameters?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I use stackoverflow for the first time.

Error Question 1. I changed  n or 4, 16 etc..   result = compile error

Error Question 2. It is not possible to call '2 Dimensional Array' with 'User Defined Function'.

Sorry for the incorrect grammar.

```
void outputarr(int n, int (*arr)[**n**]){        //n error
    ...
}

void inputarr(int n, int (*arr)[**n**]){         //n error
    ...
```

}

```
int main(void){
    int input;
    int *input2;

    cin >> input;

    cout << "Length of Array : " << input << '\n';

    input2 = &input;

    int **arr = new int*[input]; 
    for(int i=0; i<input; i++)  
        arr[i]= new int[input];


    **inputarr(input, arr);      // pass to input&output error
    outputarr(input, arr);**     // pass to input&output error



    for(int i=0; i<input; i++)  
        delete[] arr[i];
        delete[] arr;   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *It is not possible to call '2 Dimensional Array* -- There are no two dimensional arrays in your program.  A pointer-to-pointer is not a 2 dimensional array.  If you declare an `int**`, you must pass an `int**` to the function, and the function must take an `int**`, or reference to it.

Comment: There are no two dimensional arrays in your program. A pointer-to-pointer is not a 2 dimensional array.
thank you!!

Comment: You probably mean something like detailed in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724171/passing-an-array-by-reference But this only works for static arrays, you can't use this syntax when you just use pointers. Use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Also is `void outputarr(int n, int (*arr)[**n**])` supposed to be markup for bold text? because it's no C++ syntax and markup doesn't work in code.

Comment: Thank you Reply  churill

yes.  Expressed in bold. It is not coding.

   **n**   //  blod text meas 
**inputarr(input, arr); outputarr(input, arr);**    //  blod text meas