# How to convert an array decay to a pointer into a vector without knowing the array size?

Tags: c++

I have an array which I want to convert in vector. I have this code :

```
int function(int A[], int K){
    vector<int> v,temp1,temp2;
    for(int i = 0; A[i] != 0; ++i) v.push_back(A[i]);
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    int n = v.size();
    cout << n << endl;
}
```

And I try this code with the following test :

```
int main(){
    int tab[] {4,9,8,2,6};
    int sol = function(tab,3);
    cout << sol << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And it displays 18 while I expect 5 as a value, I don't understand why

Comment: You cannot do that because the size is not known.

Comment: inside `function` the parameter `A` is just a pointer, any information on size or where the array ends is lost.

Comment: you can copy `tab` to a vector in `main`

Comment: I stop the for loop when I have a 0, it isn't enough to stop the loop and get the good number of element in A which is non null ?

Comment: there is no `0` in the array, hence you access elements beyond the size of the array and invoke undefined behavior

Comment: `tab` has no zeros. Why do you expect `A` to have them?

Comment: Okay, thank you, I think I will just use the STL

Comment: A workaround is to add a `0` at the end of the array. Better is to provide the size of the array to the function

Comment: @Damien the better is to not use a c-array in the first place

Comment: why do you pass `K` and then do nothing with it?

Comment: Is it possible to use an array from the STL without knowing the size ? I see we need to know the size by initialisation, for example array<int,4> for an array with 4 element

Comment: Because I selected a piece of code, I just forgot to remove K @Artefacto

Comment: btw as `tab` is an array (not just a pointer to one), there is also the possibility to pass the array via reference. However, its a bit advanced, it requires you to understand quite a bit for little benefit over a `std::vector` or `std::array`,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724171/passing-an-array-by-reference

Comment: for dynamically sized arrays (ie size only known at runtime) use `std::vector`