# Why am I receiving "clang++: error - no matching function for call to '<function>'"?

Tags: c++, clang++

I have a simple function in C++ that checks whether a given element exists in a given array and return `true` or `false` accordingly. Here is an example of the code and how I am trying to use it:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool find_elem(string array[], string elem)
{
    return (find(begin(array), end(array), elem) != end(array));
}

int main(void)
{
    string names[] = {"Bob", "Bill", "Sally", "Mark"}

    if (find_elem(names, "Bob))
    {
        cout << "Bob is in the array" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Bob is not in the array" << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting an error message on the return statement for the `find_elem()` function saying `clang++: error - no matching function for call to 'begin'` as well as two more that say the same for `end`. I am not sure why this is happening because this line of code works just fine in the `main()` function of my program, but if I try to use it anywhere else, it returns an error. Can somebody explain why this is happening and how I might fix it? I only recently started learning C++ so examples or suggestions for how to do this better would be more than welcome.

Comment: What is `order`?

Comment: Oh whoops. Order is the wrong name. It is supposed to be array. I will change that

Comment: @UnholySheep I think it answers the "why" part of my question, but not the "how do I fix it" part. using the `by_pointer` method, I get new errors saying `unknown type name 'T'` and `use of undeclared identifier 'U'`. I don't really understand what these are so a better explaination would be helpful

Comment: `T` is supposed to be replaced with a type (in your case `string`)  and `U` has to be a compile-time constant (in your case 4) - the latter is explained in the answer

Comment: Another question that might be relevant is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724171/passing-an-array-by-reference

Comment: Use a `std::vector<std::string>` instead of an array, and things will work much better. Also, you need to `#include <algorithm>` to use `std::find()` as well as `#include <string>` for `std::string`.