# Can we iterate through an array passed to a function using for-each loop?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, foreach

I know we can iterate through an array passed as an argument in this way:

```cpp
// NO ERROR
void fun(int *a, int n){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cout<<a[i];
}
```

But, is there any way I could iterate through an array using a for-each loop inside a function like this?

```cpp
// ERROR
void fun(int *a, int n){
    for(auto x:a)
        cout<<x;
}
```

Comment: `a` is a pointer not an array. You know that it points to the first element of an array, but that does not make it an array

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Technically, it isn't necessarily the *first* element :)

Comment: @eerorika its not necessarily any element of an array. But I get your point, and the solution i posted as answer is rather limited compared to OPs original

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A pointer is not an array. If you pass a pointer to the first element of an array to a function then its no longer an array, but a pointer.

You can use a range based loop when you [pass the array by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724171/passing-an-array-by-reference):

```
#include <iostream>

template <size_t N>
void foo(int (&x)[N]) {
    for (int i : x) std::cout << i << " ";
}

int main() {
    int x[] = {1,2,3};
    foo(x);
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3
```

This works, because the range based loop uses `std::begin(x)` and `std::end(x)` to get iterators to the begin and end of the array. Pointers don't have a begin or end.

Comment: Well, you could `template <class Container> void foo(Container&& c);` if it's going to be a template anyway.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili right, though I wanted to stay close to OPs code. I'd rather remove the template and accept only fixed size

Answer (score 6):

In C++20, you can use [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span):

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>
#include <span>

void foo(int* arr, std::size_t sz) {
  std::span<int> span{arr, sz};
  for (int elm : span) {
    std::printf("%d\n", elm);
  }
}
```

Or you could make `span` the input argument in the first place:

```
void foo(std::span<int> span) {
  for (int elm : span) {
    std::printf("%d\n", elm);
  }
}
```

If the signature of the function is flexible, I suggest you use the second option.

Pre C++20, [here](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/main/include/gsl/span#L398) is an implementation of `span` from GSL. Or make your own wrapper class with `begin()` and `end()` functions.

Comment: If using `std::span`, I would recommend changing the function to accept `std::span` directly as the parameter. That way the function can be called like `foo(arr);`.

Comment: @eerorika I thought about it. But didn't do it because OP could be stuck with the signature. I'll add that as an option. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative non-template C++20 solution:

```
auto range = std::views::counted(arr, sz);
for (auto elm : range) {
```

The benefit of this compared to `std::span` is that this is more general and works with any  iterator, not requiring a contiguous iterator such as a pointer.

The benefit of using `std::span` instead of this is that you can use `std::span` as the function parameter without making it a template.

---

Alternative template solution (works pre C++20):

```
template <class Range>
void foo(const Range& range) {
    for (auto elm : range) {
```

The benefit of this compared to `int (&arr)[N]` is that it is much more general. This template works with **all** ranges.

---

Besides range-for, you could consider avoiding the loop entirely (works pre C++20):

```
auto print = [](auto elm) {
    std::cout << elm;
}
std::for_each_n(arr, sz, print);
```

I recommend this if you don't have C++20, cannot have boost / ranges / GSL libraries for some reason, and cannot have a template.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can. Just pass the array by reference to a template function:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
template <size_t N> void foo(int (&arr)[N])
{
    for (auto i:arr)
        cout << i << " ";
}
 
int main()
{
    int array[] = { 5, 17, 3452, 546546, 756756, 75675, 756753, 345, 53};
    foo(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And the real answer:

```
int made[] = {10 , 2 ,15};
 std::for_each(std::begin(made),std::end(made),[=](auto x){ std::cout << x << std::endl; });
```

You can parallelize `std::for_each` with say `std::execution::par`.

With function code will be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <execution>

void f(int (&made)[3])
{
     std::for_each(std::begin(made),std::end(made),[=](auto x){ std::cout << "and then " << x << std::endl; });
}

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{

    int made[] = {10 , 2 ,15};
    f(made);
}
```