# What does "non const-qualified" mean?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to pass an array by reference to `funcA`.

```
void funcA(int(&a)[], int k);

int main() {
    int n = 5;
    int x[5];
    funcA(x, n);
    return 0;
}
```

However when I try to, it throws this error.

```
 A reference of type "int (&)[]" (non const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "int [5]"
```

I tried to find what "non const-qualified" meant, but there weren't any good explanations anywhere. Can someone please explain what it means? Thank you.

Comment: means compiler can't convert `int [5]` to `int (&)[]`, but I don't know how to fix this

Comment: [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724171/passing-an-array-by-reference) some reference for you `on how to pass statically allocated array by reference`

Comment: The error message is bogus (using XL or PGI C++ ?). That's because there are no references to an array of unknown size in C++. So `int(&)[]` is an impossibility. Use `int[]`, `int*` or `int(&)[5]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you cannot have a reference to an array of unbound size. The closest thing is a reference to a pointer (to the array), i.e. `int * (&a)`. This still gives a problem because `a` is not constant and the passed parameter `x` is a constant (the location of the array) - this is actually what the compiler error in the question is referring to. Hence, we need `a` to be a reference to a constant pointer to a non-constant array, i.e.:

```
void funcA(int * const (&a), int k)
{
    a[k-1] = 0;  // Just a dummy example
}

int main() {
    int n = 5;
    int x[5];
    funcA(x, n);
    return 0;
}
```

It should be mentioned that there is no downside to using the more common form of passing an array instead:

```
void funcA(int *a, int k)
```