# Error: expected ',' or '...' before '(' token - Why?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
template<size_t N>
size_t sendProgmem(WiFiClient client, const String prog_char(&str)[N])
// size_t sendProgmem(WiFiClient client, const prog_char (&str)[N])
{
  return sendProgmem(client, str, N);
}

size_t sendProgmem(WiFiClient client, const String prog_char progmem[], size_t size) {
    size_t maxSize=2920; // this seems to be the max that write() will ever actually send
    size_t sent=0;

    while(sent < size) {
      size_t sendSize = (maxSize < (size - sent)) ? maxSize : (size - sent);
      sent += client.write(progmem+sent, sendSize); // write() may send less than you asked it to
    }
    return sent;
}
```

The original line (3rd line of code, now commented) produced an error:

```
 "ISO C++ forbids declaration with no type"
```

so I added String (see 2nd line of code).

Now I get,

```
error: expected ',' or '...' before '(' token
    2 | size_t sendProgmem(WiFiClient client, const String prog_char(&str)[N])
```

The original code is some 5+ years old. I'm not a C++ programmer so I don't even know where to start.

Any help as to where I can start looking or what is wrong with this syntax?

Also, what is the basic explanation of '(&str)[N]'?

Comment: what is `String`? Can you post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 3):

Supposed `prog_char` is a type, the original signature was correct:

```
struct prog_char {};
struct WiFiClient {};

auto sendProgmem(auto,auto,auto){}

template<size_t N>
size_t sendProgmem(WiFiClient client, const prog_char(&str)[N])
{
  return sendProgmem(client, str, N);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/d5bMhbb38).

The function is taking an array of `prog_char` by reference. The size of the array, `N`, is the template argument and deduced from the parameter passed to the function. See [Passing an array by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724171/passing-an-array-by-reference) for more on that (scroll down for an answer that also mentions deducing the size).

This

```
size_t sendProgmem(WiFiClient client, const String prog_char(&str)[N])
```

as well as this:

```
size_t sendProgmem(WiFiClient client, const String prog_char progmem[], size_t size)
```

is wrong syntax. The compiler gets confused and spits out confusing error messages. Moreover `String` is not a standard C++ type.

The error message

```
"ISO C++ forbids declaration with no type"
```

for the original code can be caused by different things. It could be that `prog_char` is not declared, or that `prog_char` is declared but not as a type, or something else.

Comment: Thank you for your great explanations and help. I'll go back to the project and do some more digging - now that I have a better understanding.