# why i cant return 2 value in a user defined function and display it in the main functionn? can someone help me

Tags: c++

this countGender function need to receive what gender and return 2 value which is female or male

```
    int countGender(string gender)
    {
        int numGender[2] = {0};
        
        if(gender == "F")
        numGender[1]++;
        else if(gender == "M")
        numGender[2]++;
        
        return numGender[2];
    }
```

display the 2 value in the main function

```
    int main()
    {
        string gender;
        int numGender[2];
        int n;
        
        cout<<"Enter number of respondents:";
        cin>>n;
        
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
        cout<<"\nEnter Gender (F-Female, M-Male):";
        cin>>gender;
        numGender=countGender(gender);
        }
        cout<<"\nFemale - "<<numGender[1];
        cout<<"\nMale - "<<numGender[2];
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `numGender[2]++;` and `return numGender[2];` introduce _undefined behavior_. Indexing in c++ starts at zero. What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: In the countGender function, i want to use array to store 2 value which is numGender[1] to represent female and numGender[2] to represent male. In the main function, i want to call that function and display the 2 value. Or maybe there is another alternative?

Comment: So you might use 2 reference parameters for output. The function can pass only one value back to the called via the return value. Something like `void countGender(string gender, int& countMale, int& countFemale);`

Comment: ohhh okay now i undestand, thank you so much for your advice:)

Answer (score 0):

You're mismatching effect of function and object you want to store results. THe `countGender` function looks like a mess resulting of shotgun debugging.

You can't return an array in a function. More of, to actually perform counting, you have to pass existing value on each iteration. One of logical things to do is to pass the array by [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724171/passing-an-array-by-reference/5724184#5724184). Also, array in C++ have zero-based indexes.

```
void countGender(int (&numGender)[2], string gender)
{    
    if(gender == "F") 
        numGender[0]++; 
    else if(gender == "M") 
        numGender[1]++; 
}

int main()
{
    string gender;
    int numGender[2] = {};
    int n;
    
    cout<<"Enter number of respondents:";
    cin>>n;
    
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout<<"\nEnter Gender (F-Female, M-Male):";
        cin>>gender;
        countGender(numGender,gender);
    }
    cout<<"\nFemale - "<<numGender[0];
    cout<<"\nMale - "<<numGender[1];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your comment, now i understand and I really appreciate you taking the time to write

Comment: Hi, just want to ask. For the countGender function, what is the difference when i use int return type instead of void? (btw both works) or i can just use either one?

Comment: @Dequavis difference is that you would need to return something relevant (you have to do so in all control paths or else), e,g. a enum telling which gender was chosen, but `countGender`  would be superfluous in that case. What you as trying to return wasn't relevant at all, you was trying to return a possibly uninitialized element of array created inside of function but you actually returned value at memory location beyond that array.