# Passing arrays by reference in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, reference, pass-by-reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is useful about a reference-to-array parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188991/what-is-useful-about-a-reference-to-array-parameter)
>   [How do I use arrays in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

I am trying to pass the arrays by reference. The problem is I am getting errors for passing these arrays.

> error C2664: 'InitializeArrays' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int [64]' to 'int (&)[]'

Here is the code:

```
void InitializeS(int (&s)[], int (&BeforeDecimal1)[]);

int main()
{
   int BeforeDecimal[128],s[128];

   InitializeS(s,BeforeDecimal);

   return 0;
}

void InitializeS(int (&s)[], int (&BeforeDecimal1)[])
{
    for(int i=0;i<128;i++)
    {
        s[i]=0;
        BeforeDecimal1[i]=0;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot pass the arrays by reference without a size.

Comment: Look [this useful FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c).

Comment: You probably want `std::vector<int>` instead of C style int arrays.

Comment: But sometimes I pass arrays of different sizes to this function, thats why I didn't put specific size in there

Comment: Then you should write a function template taking the size as a template parameter.

Comment: @Alfred, and that is exactly why you have a bug in `InitializeS` when you overwrite your `s` array which has 50 elements while you write 128 elements to it :)  Yes, I know it's an example, but that is essentially the reason why you need size

Comment: Actually the size of s is 128. This is typo

Comment: @Alfred: Sometimes I have people of varying sizes in my car so I just took out the seats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ there is unlike as in C no concept of compatible types and the type T[] is unrelated to T[N]. You need to make the reference have a size and the size must equal the one of the array you pass.

C++ also bans references to arrays without bounds as function parameter types (perhaps for this reason).

Comment: It is an array without size. Incomplete type

Comment: Are you a full time programmer? Man how do you keep all this stuff in mind.I forget things when I don't work in C++ for a while

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: That is better :)

Comment: @Alfred: Everybody has an area of expertise!

Answer (score 3):

#### Why yours doesn't work

The "array" function argument syntax `void foo(int array[])` is misleading in that it has nothing to do with arrays. It is syntactic "sugar" *(read: horribly legacy confusion that we're stuck with)* for `void foo(int* array)`.

As such, `void foo(int (&array)[])` doesn't do what you think it does. It's not even equivalent to `void foo(int*& array)`. In fact, the syntax simply doesn't exist.

---

#### Passing arrays by reference

Real arrays have dimensions and these dimensions are part of the static type (and *everywhere* that you see `int[]` as a "type" is either using it as an *incomplete type*, or is merely syntactic sugar for something else), so you will need to state the dimension with the type:

```
void foo(int (&array)[5])
```

or use templates:

```
template <size_t N>
void foo(int (&array)[N])
```

---

#### What if I can't do that?

If you don't know the dimension at compile-time then you are SOL and will have to use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: ...unless you declare `extern int a[];` in which case `a` really *is* an array and *not* a pointer.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Okay, so `int[]` exists as an _incomplete_ type.

Answer (score 0):

As FredOverflow suggests, you need to use templates to implement this functionality.

Here is a way to implement it:

```
template<int S1, int S2> void InitializeS(int(&)[S1], int(&)[S2]);

int main()
{
   int BeforeDecimal[100],s[50];

   InitializeS(s,BeforeDecimal);

   return 0;
}

template<int S1, int S2> void InitializeS(int (&s)[S1], int (&BeforeDecimal1)[S2])
{
    for(int i=0;i<128;i++)
    {
        s[i]=0;
        BeforeDecimal1[i]=0;
    }
}
```

Note that this only works if the size of the arrays is known at compile-time.